# Blazor WASM - query Sql

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

Estou a tentar fazer uma query de um bd no meu projeto Blazor WASM, mas não sei como fazer em C# por ainda estar a aprender. A base de dados contém moradas e suas respetivas coordenadas(latitude,longitude) e queria usar uma query para dar fetch as coordenadas para depois serem usadas para mostrar pontos num mapa.

Estou a usar o .net7.0 ASP.NETCORE.

não sei se a minha ideia é a melhor para o que estou a fazer. Por isso se tiverem alguma outra maneira de o fazer, sem ser com uma bd, mencionem.